# Is there a way to get this type of chart using Jfreechart? I want my line or bar chart to be look like as the image attached

Tags: jfreechart

I am new to Jfreechart and I need a chart that will look like the image I have attached. Can someone please help me with how to make it done?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Either you want to know _if_ there's a way to make this type of chart – then the answer would be yes or no with some description. Or you want to know _how_ to implement it – StackOverflow is not for this kind of question. You research, try to write code, and if it goes wrong – welcome to ask.

Comment: You might review the [demos](https://jfree.github.io/jfreechart-demo-programs/) for likely candidates.